# Overlapping Labels in Pie-Chart

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008

Are there any Settings to avoid having overlapping labels in a Pie Chart in SSRS?
I have several Charts with the same Problem, if the Slices are too small the Text will overlap. Here is a Picture of my Problem and a possible way as how i want it to be:

[image: Pie-Chart showing overlapping labels and a Version as how it should be]

EDIT
edited the 3D Options so the Labels fit in like I wanted them to be. But another Problem occurred when setting rotation and inclination to zero, the colors aren't as intensive as they where before:

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try this..

1)On the design surface, right-click outside the pie chart but inside the chart borders and select Chart Area Properties.The Chart Area Properties dialog box appears.

2)On the 3D Options tab, select Enable 3D.

3)If you want the chart to have more room for labels but still appear two-dimensional, set the Rotation and Inclination properties to 0.

Comment: It helps a lot, thanks! But the Colors are not as intensive as they were before because the 3D-Effekt forced them to be very light like a shadow, is there also a trick to get them displayed in the full colors?

Comment: You can play with palette in the chart properties and also you can create a own custom palette colors ...

Comment: So, this doesn't realy help, i edited my question to show a picture of my new problem.....

Answer (score 16):

to solve this:

- go to the Chart Area Properties,
- the Chart Area Properties dialog box appears.
- expand Area3DStlye
- For Shading Property select: "Simple"

[image: Reporting Services Designer]

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by an emulation of a diffuse lighting effect. The following code worked in the former dundas chart for area charts:

Chart1.ChartAreas("Default").Area3DStyle.Light = LightStyle.None;

should be something similar for the pies.

Comment: this answer is not related to the reporting services charts

Answer (score 0):

[Note: The first 3 parts of this is the same text as answered by Swathi, but there was a follow-up comment question that was not known that I discovered the answer to concerning the colors looking muted after making it 3-D. I would add a comment but I don't have enough karma now.]

1)On the design surface, right-click outside the pie chart but inside the chart borders and select Chart Area Properties.The Chart Area Properties dialog box appears.

2)On the 3D Options tab, select Enable 3D.

3)If you want the chart to have more room for labels but still appear two-dimensional, set the Rotation and Inclination properties to 0.

4) If you want the colors to not be muted when using 3-D to simulate 2-D, under Appearance/Area3DStyle change the Shading to None.